cGAN:the generator loss and discriminator loss of conditional generative adversarial network
After learning that gan can be used to generate image data, I wanted to use gan to generate array data. Since my array data has labels, I chose to use cGAN to complete this work.
However, the performance of Cgan's generator loss and discriminator loss is not very ideal. When I generated other similar data before, the generator loss curve and discriminator loss curve tended to stabilize around 0.69 after a period of training.As shown below.
enter image description here
But my current curve is like this
enter image description here
I'm confused about where the curve is going and don't know where to optimize now.
This is my cgan initialization code
def __init__(self):
        self.rows = 64
        self.cols = 32
        self.shape = (self.rows,self.cols)
        self.num_classes = 28
        self.latent_dim = 4096
        
        self.generator = self.build_generator()
        self.discriminator = self.build_discriminator()
        self.discriminator.compile(loss=['binary_crossentropy'],optimizer=Adam(0.0001,0.1),metrics=['accuracy'])
        
        noise = Input(shape(self.latent_dim,))
        label = Input(shape(1,))
        img = self.generator([noise,label])
        self.discriminator.trainable = False
        valid = self.discriminator([img,label])
        self.combined = Model([noise,label],valid)
        self.combined.compile(loss=['binary_crossentropy'],optimizer=Adam(0.0002,0.5),metrics=['accuracy'])

This is my generator network code
    def build_generator(self):
        
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(512,input_dim = self.latent_dim))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.05))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9))
        model.add(Dense(512))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.05))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9))
        model.add(Dense(1024))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.05))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9))
        model.add(Dense(1024))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.05))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9))
        model.add(Dense(1024))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.05))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9))
        model.add(Dense(1024))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.05))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9))
    
        model.add(Dense(np.prod(self.shape), activation='tanh'))
        model.add(Reshape(self.shape))
        model.summary()
    
        noise = Input(shape=(self.latent_dim,))
        label = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32')
    
        label_embedding = Flatten()(Embedding(self.num_classes, self.latent_dim)(label))
    
        model_input = multiply([noise, label_embedding])
    
        img = model(model_input)
    
        return Model([noise, label], img)

This is my discriminator network code
    def build_discriminator(self):
        
        
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(256,input_dim=np.prod(self.shape)))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
        model.add(Dense(256))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        model.add(Dense(256))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        model.add(Dense(256))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        model.add(Dense(256))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        
        
        
        model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))

        model.summary()

        img = Input(shape=self.shape)
        label = Input(shape=(1,),dtype='int32')

        label_embedding = Flatten()(Embedding(self.num_classes,np.prod(self.shape))(label))
        flat_img = Flatten()(img)

        model_input = multiply([flat_img,label_embedding])

        validity = model(model_input)
        return Model([img,label],validity)

here is the whole Train code
   def train(self,epochs,X_data,y_data,batch_size,sample_interval):
        
        X_train = X_data
        Y_train = y_data
        Y_train = np.array(Y_train)
        valid = np.ones((batch_size, 1))
        fake = np.zeros((batch_size, 1))
        d_loss_history = []
        g_losses = []
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            idx = np.random.randint(0,X_train.shape[0],int(batch_size))
            imgs,labels = X_train[idx],Y_train[idx]

            noise = np.random.normal(0,1,(int(batch_size),self.latent_dim))
            gen_imgs = self.generator.predict([noise,labels])
            
            
            

            d_loss_real = self.discriminator.train_on_batch([imgs,labels],valid)
            d_loss_fake = self.discriminator.train_on_batch([gen_imgs,labels],fake)
            d_loss = 0.5*np.add(d_loss_real,d_loss_fake)
            d_loss_history.append(d_loss[0])
        
        
            noise = np.random.normal(0,1,(int(batch_size),self.latent_dim))
            possible_values = np.arange(1, 28)
            sampled_label = np.random.choice(possible_values, size=batch_size)
            sampled_label = sampled_label.reshape(batch_size, 1)
            g_loss = self.combined.train_on_batch([noise,sampled_label],valid)

            g_losses.append(g_loss[0])
            print("%d [D loss:%f,acc:%.2f%%][G loss:%f]" % (epoch,float(d_loss[0]),float(100*d_loss[1]),float(g_loss[0])))
        plt.plot(d_loss_history, label='Discriminator Loss',color=(223/255, 122/255, 94/255))
        plt.plot(g_losses, label='Generator Loss',color=(130/255, 178/255, 154/255))
        plt.legend()
        plt.xlabel('Epoch',fontsize = 12)
        plt.ylabel('Loss',fontsize = 12)
        plt.show()

So if anyone can help me optimize this network model to reach a stable situation, I would be very grateful, or if you have any other ideas after seeing my problem,welcome to share it with me.
